# How to improve performance of rendering?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have service that adds each time response data to array: `group: [].`

Where response is object:

```
{"items": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]}
```

Problem is that it is rendered so long in template and renders each time when changes comes to array `group`:

```
<div class="SearchResultGroup" *ngFor="let layer of group">
   <div class="SearchResultGroup" *ngFor="let l of layer.items"></div>
</div>
```

How to improve performance of rendering?

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. Use the `angular` tag if your question is about Angular in general and the one specific version of Angular that you are using, if the question is specific to that version and only that version.

Comment: your issue is most likely because of the many elements rendered in the dom. ideally, you want to render **only items within the current view of the user**, I suggest you look into virtual scrolling of the CDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take control of when change detection occurs by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent  {
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  someMethod(): void {
    // do lots of heavy stuff

    // now trigger change detection

    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the decorator indicates that you will tell Angular when to run change detection.

`this.changeDetector.detectChanges()` tells Angular that you are now ready for it to run change detection.

This strategy means that you can silently update your model and trigger change detection in one go.

Comment: Maybe to use Map() instead array or no matter?

Comment: Depends on what operations you're performing. Map is better for indexed retrieval. Arrays are great for pushing new stuff into them and iterating over. Kind of depends on your use case. I don't see how Map would improve your performance from your small code snippet - although I appreciate you may have made it trivial for the question.

Comment: Does  ` mapData | keyvalue` work better that array in template?

Comment: Think you're going to need to create a stackblitz to demonstrate this :)